# Междометие "ну"

Tags: пунктуация, междометие

> Нет, ну это вообще смешно!

Правильно ли написано предложение?

Comment: @Аршинская Анна, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

> *Нет, ну это вообще смешно! Правильно
> ли написано предложение?*

Правильно. В этом предложении ***"ну"*** -- частица. См. http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_501 :

> ***НУ,*** *частица и междометие*
>
> 1. Частица. Служит для усиления последующего высказывания... Интонационно (и знаками препинания) не отделяется от последующих слов...
> 2. Междометие. Выражает побуждение, удивление. Междометие «ну»
>    интонационно отделяется от
>    последующего слова и обособляется.
>
> *«Мама-мама, – ухватил он ее за фартук, – мама же, **ну**, смотри!..»*
>
> @ Зачастую сложно различить частицу
> «ну» и междометие «ну» по значению. В
> этих случаях следует ориентироваться
> на интонацию.